# Cannot read Outlook Sent Items with Blue Prism Mapiex Get Mail function

Tags: outlook, blueprism

I tested reading mail from Sent Items with BP Mapiex Get Mail, but it only works with Inbox (default folder in action). Folder name is correct (I took it as I see it in Outlook).

> Error message: Failure in Get Mail function of Blue Prism Extended
>   MAPI Automation. Failed to open sub-folder 'Sent Items'.

Would anyone have any ideas, what can help it work with Sent Items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `Get Mail` was configured to look in the Inbox only (and sub folders within the inbox). You can add a rule in Outlook to move the sent items to a sub-folder (then you use the `Get Mail` action), or add a new page in your MAPIEx object. If you go with the latter, you can proceed like this:

1. Open the MAPIEx object and duplicate the page called 'Get Mail', rename the page and the code stage to something else, such as `Get Sent Items`, then publish it. I did it this way:

   [image]
2. Open the code stage and edit this line (line 17) so that it looks like the following, from `OpenInbox()` to `OpenSentItems()`:

   [image]

Editing the highlighted items is optional but preferable as it makes it easier to debug should there be issues. For instance, you would change anything that says `Inbox` to `Sent Items`.

From there you can call the action from your process just like you would call `Get Mail`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I'm going to implement it asap.